# Calculate averages of multiple IEnumerable with same item count

Tags: c#, linq, average, ienumerable

Assuming we have multiple `IEnumerable`s of the same item count

```
var multipleEnumerables = new[]
{
    new[] { 10, 20, 30 }
    new[] { 11, 21, 31 }
    new[] { 12, 22, 32 }
    new[] { 13, 23, 33 }
}
```

How can i get the average of those using LINQ which will yield the following result:

```
new[] { 11.5, 21.5, 31.5 }
```

The number of enumerables may vary (i.e. not fixed to four).

The number of items in each enumerable may vary (i.e. not fixed to three) but will be the same for all the enumerables for that particular instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update in response to edit**

If you have `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Item>>` you could use something like this:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Test>> multipleEnumerables = new[] {
    new [] { new Test {  Value = 10 }, new Test {  Value = 20 } },
    new [] { new Test {  Value = 11 }, new Test {  Value = 21 } }
};

var averages = multipleEnumerables
    .SelectMany(e => e.Select((v, i) => new { Index = i, Item = v }))
    .GroupBy(e => e.Index)
    .Select(e => e.Select(v => v.Item.Value).Average())
    .ToArray();
```

If you have a simple `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>`, change the `.Select` line to: `.Select(e => e.Select(v => v.Item).Average())` (but based on your comment, I think that isn't the case).

1. Use [`.SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany) to flatten the list into objects containing the item, and its sub-array index (so 10 and 11 will have `Index` 0, etc.).
2. Group by the index.
3. Use [`.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2) to select the average from each grouping.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/LFAYT12842)

[Try it online with question data](https://rextester.com/RXV78225)

**Original answer**

You can use [`.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.7.2) to combine the two lists and compute an average:

```
var averages = items1
                  .Zip(items2, (a, b) => (a+b)/2.0)
                  .ToArray();
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/TGXAK69594)

Comment: Thanks John! I think I oversimplified my problem. `Zip` works with two `IEnumerable`s but what if there are more than two (thus multiple)? Basically I have an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Item>>`. Would you mind if I update my question?

Comment: Genius! It might've took me a couple days to figure this out. :)) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Due to your interest in zipping more than two `IEnumerable<T>`s, here's an extension method (`ZipAll`) that shows how to zip multiple `IEnumerable<T>` together. Effectively, this rotates the data such that columns become rows.

```
public static class ZipEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ZipAll<T>(
                                   this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> src)
    {
        return src
            .Aggregate(
                (IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>)null,
                (acc, curr) => acc == null
                    ? curr.Select(x => x.ToEnumerable())
                    : acc.Zip(curr, (a, c) => a.Append(c)));
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(this T item)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Using this `ZipAll` method, it's now easy to:

```
var averages = multipleEnumerables.ZipAll().Select(x => x.Average()); //.ToArray()
```